# How to speed up post list slowed by update_meta_cache()?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, cache

Having run Query Monitor on my site, the post list for a custom post takes 18.17s. Query Monitor advises 2 Slow Queries, including...

```
SELECT term_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wpcxt_termmeta
WHERE term_id IN (5520,9186,11865,5521,9187,5522,5523,5524,5526,11833,5527,9188,5528,9189,5530,9190,9719,5531,5532,5533,5534,5535,5536,5538,5539,9314,5540,9191,5541,5542,5543,5544,
```

etc etc etc

The caller is said to be...

```
update_meta_cache()
wp-includes/meta.php:831
update_termmeta_cache()
wp-includes/taxonomy.php:1256
WP_Term_Query->get_terms()
wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php:696
WP_Term_Query->query()
wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php:288
get_terms()
wp-includes/taxonomy.php:1099
wp_terms_checklist()
wp-admin/includes/template.php:145
WP_Posts_List_Table->inline_edit()
wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php:1494
```

It refers to `112916` rows.

It is true, I have many taxonomy terms.

My post list also includes extra columns for custom post fields, added by Admin Columns Pro.

[`update_meta_cache()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_meta_cache/) "Updates the metadata cache for the specified objects."

Seems like doing this for all those terms is slowing things down.

Is there a way to do this less frequently, or otherwise to speed things up?

Comment: By default, `update_post_meta_cache` argument is true whenever running a WP_Query, you may add `update_post_meta_cache => false` to the query arguments that you don't think it need to update the cache and limit it only updating in certain occasions such as cron job, maintenance time.